# Android : Editing layout files issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

My application has a mobile UI and tablet UI. for tablet UI specific layouts are placed in layout-large folder.

What I noticed recently is, when I change the layout of tablet it changes the XML file of the phone xml file too which is in the layout folder.

I don't know why this happens. How to resolve this issue?? I hope it has something to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top of the graphical editor, you can select which layout you are editing. In no case should it edit both, though.